# Is it possible to solve recursive percent equations?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

I'm working on a program that calculates the skill level of a sports teams based on how well its done against other teams. Something along the lines of, your skill is +20% of the average skill of the teams you beat.

This quickly becomes a math problem where:

x = (y+z)/2

AND

y = (x+z)/2

AND

z = (x+y)/2

Obviously, this is not good, at least in my understanding of math. Is there a way around this? Or am I trying to do something impossible and will have to figure out some way of doing this that does not result in a potential loop?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: $3$ equations.  $3$ variables.  You have each variable as a solution of other variables.  Hm, I think it is a substitution problem of algebra?  And I don't quite understand what $x,y,z$ have anything to do with the +20% and all that.  Any connection you could expand on?

Comment: Just use the [Glicko rating system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glicko_rating_system), an improvement on the Elo rating system :)

Comment: @SimpleArt, that was a simple example showing how each value is used to calculate every other value. It's not intended to reflect the exact constraints of my problem. Basically abstracting in hopefully find a common fix.